# How to get specific value from Promise

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous

Here is part of my code returning a Promise

JS:

```
static base64URLEncode(t) {
    return t.toString("base64").replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(/\//g, "_").replace(/=/g, "")
}
```

```
function buf2Base64(buffer) {
    return (pks.constructor.base64URLEncode(pks.fromByteArray(new Uint8Array(buffer))));
}
```

```
async function test2(inputString) {    
    inputBytes = pks.constructor.textEncodeLite(inputString);
    hashBytes = await window.crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", inputBytes);    
    bufbase = buf2Base64(hashBytes);    
    return bufbase;
}
```

CONSOLE LOG:

```
Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: "xPCEgWjxihl6bIHJfpjrebwZzg0cn83ZokhVEwRVG2w" }
​
<state>: "fulfilled"
​
<value>: "xPCEgWjxihl6bIHJfpjrebwZzg0cn83ZokhVEwRVG2w"
​
<prototype>: Promise.prototype { … }
```

How I can get string value `<value>` from the object Promise Result?

What i have tried so far which returns `"{}"`

```
JSON.stringify(test2(pks.generateCodeVerifier()));
```

Comment: Only by using `.then`, or `await`. The linked dupe discusses both ways, as well as the reasons for this.

Comment: @Amadan Thank you for the suggestions, finally figured it out from the duplicates you pointed out using `.then`